# Problem with Wordpress plugin sending base64 image data via Ajax - 400/404/500 errors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, base64

I'm Developing a WordPress plugin for customers to design custom T-Shirts, with the option of uploading their own images. The plugin takes several screenshots and emails them to a print department.

In Javascript I convert the screenshots to base64 data, which is then sent via Ajax to a PHP file, this creates a folder for the customer's design, creates the images from the data and stores the screenshots in there.

Most screenshots/base64 data send across just fine, for example just adding in text creates no problems. However if the user uploads an image and it's scaled up too much it causes various errors (sometimes 400 error, sometimes 404 and sometimes 500).

Running this through my local setup on Windows with Wamp, it's fine. I can upload images and scale them to 12x with no issues. However when I try this with the live site, I get the above problems if I scale any of the images past 4x, and with most images this happens if I even try to scale them up at all past 1x.

The resolution/file size of the image seems to have an effect, though not in an obvious way. I can send a huge plain red square, or normal image at 1x scale.

At first I thought this was a POST data limit issue, except the live site's POST limit is double that what I had set on my WAMP setup, which doesn't have this problem.

Also, and even stranger. I tested uploading the image but replacing the base64 data with simple characters (so the scaled up image exists in the page but it's base64 data isn't sent via POST), and I still have the same issue. So I don't think it's a simple POST limit issue.

Cannot for the life of me find a solution to this, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you check [WordPress' debug.log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) for clues? If there have been any PHP notice/warning/error messages related to your issue that's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show anything related to this specific issue

Comment: In that case you'll have to share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here so we can help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured a way round it, I'll give my solution in case anyone else has the same issue and comes across this post.

Basically I converted my base64 image data to a blob, and appended that to a newly created formData object. I found that also appending my nonce and action (amended to work with the admin-ajax way of using AJAX) to the formData helped deal with most issues on the javascript side. In the AJAX request I set processData and contentType to false.

As for the PHP side, I set a variable equal to the specific $_FILES array element I just sent. I used file_get_contents() on that variable (i.e the blob data), and wrapped that in file_put_contents() to actually write the image.

That's the quick version. If anyone wants a more detailed explanation let me know.